# Unable to upload pdf compliance greater than 1.3 in AWS S3 bucket through lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload the pdf version greater than 1.3 in S3 bucket through AWS lambda. The file is getting uploaded but if i download, file is totally blank. This occurs only in pdf verison greater than 1.3. Is anything need to be changed in lambda java code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the size of the PDF file because AWS lambda has a maximum invocation/payload size (6MB for synchronous and 256kb for asynchronous). Make sure that the size of the file uploaded does not exceed this. Otherwise, the lambda function would just process the first 6MB and reject the exceeding section which causes the corruption of the file.

If your use-case requires support to larger files, I would recommend utilizing a file chunk upload mechanism to upload the file part by part. Once all the chunks/parts of the file reach the server-side, you can merge them together and upload it to the s3 bucket.

S3 supports multipart upload! You can learn more about it in this section:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/

Comment: but all the pdf files am uploading is under 1 MB

Comment: Hi @yuvanath, I just verified in AWS lambda documentation that asynchronous endpoints have a 256kb size limitation. Can you try to make your API synchronous?

Comment: Thanks for the information. So above 256 kb we need to send it as chunk right??

Comment: Yes u are right, cut it into packet smaller size than 256 so u still have some extra space

Comment: But i tried uploading a pdf file size less than 256kb then also is displaying blank pages in s3 and also am not doing any async call. API is sync only